# Type Specifier for ImmutableMap with Polymorphic Class Value?

Tags: java, oop, guava, factory, factory-pattern

I'm trying to use an `ImmutableMap` to create a named dictionary of class types:

```
private static final Map<String, Class<FruitFactory>> REGISTERED_FACTORIES =
    ImmutableMap.of(
        "AppleOrchard", AppleFactory.class,
        "OrangeGrove",  OrangeFactory.class
    );
```

Where `FruitFactory` is an interface:

```
public interface FruitFactory {
    Fruit createFruit();
}
```

And `AppleFactory` and `OrangeFactory` are implementations thereof:

```
public class AppleFactory implements FruitFactory {
    @Override
    public Fruit createFruit() {
        return new Apple();
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class OrangeFactory implements FruitFactory {
    @Override
    public Fruit createFruit() {
        return new Orange();
    }
}
```

**The problem** is that this does not compile. I get the following build error from my `ImmutableMap.of(` call:

```
 error: incompatible types: inference variable V has incompatible bounds

equality constraints: Class<FruitFactory>
lower bounds: Class<AppleFactory>,Class<OrangeFactory>
```

Ultimately I think the solution lies in some wild generics syntax with my initial map declaration `Map<String, CRZNSS> REGISTERED_FACTORIES`. I have tried several iterations of `?`, `T`, `foo extends bar`, etc. etc., but nothing works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `Map<String, Class<? extends FruitFactory>>`

Comment: See also [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

Comment: Thanks @shmosel! That was the one. I wish Java had a `typedef`. Later on, when I iterate over this map, I have an object of type `Set<Map.Entry<String, Class<? extends FruitFactory>>> `.  Yipes.

Comment: How about `REGISTERED_FACTORIES.forEach((key, value) -> ...)`?

Comment: @shmosel Oh yea! Good idea.